# distance in 3D binary array to nearest point of other type

Tags: python, numpy, euclidean-distance

I have a 3D numpy array consisting of 1's and zeros defining open versus filled space in a porous solid (it's currently a numpy Int64 array).  I want to determine the euclidian distance from each of the "1" points (voxels) to its nearest zero point. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Would "1" point mean `1` across all three axes `x`,`y` & `z`'s?

Answer (score 4):

What you are asking for is the [distance transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform), which you can compute using scipy's `ndimage` package and its [`distance_transform_edt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt.html) function:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import scipy.ndimage as ndi
>>> img = np.random.randint(2, size=(5, 5))
>>> img
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
>>> ndi.distance_transform_edt(img)
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.41421356],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.41421356],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  2.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.41421356,  2.23606798]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If `val` contains the value (0 or 1) and `pos` contains the positions of each of these voxels, then you could use `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` to compute all pairwise distances:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
# Find the points corresponding to zeros and ones
zero_indices = (val == 0)
one_indices = (val == 1)
# Compute all pairwise distances between zero-points and one-points
pairwise_distances = distance.cdist(pos[zero_indices, :], pos[one_indices, :])
# Choose the minimum distance
min_dist = np.min(pairwise_distances, axis=0)
```

Comment: Actually, now that I read your question again, I notice that you say you have a 3D array of 0's and 1's. Could it be that `pos` for you is simply the (x, y, z) indices of the 0's and 1's in this matrix?

Comment: yes, the data were taken from an X-ray CT image, so the (x,y,z) positions in the array give the spatial positions of the datapoints

Comment: one point, though, is that there may be a large number of points - there are 512 x 512 x 512 or 1024 x 1024 x 1024 images

Comment: If the number of voxels is that large, then you may not be able to hold `pairwise_distances` in memory. I don't think there could be a "simple" implementation like your question asks, then... If the number of zeros is much smaller than the number of 1's, then you could start from each zero and update the distance of surrounding 1-voxels iteratively. Some kind of dynamic programming approach... I'm not sure how to implement it, though.

Comment: often it will be the other way around - mom any more zeros than 1's. the ones are connected pixels from skimage.measure.label

Comment: I', also testing on a 16 x 16 x 16 for now

Comment: so how should I modify the above with the positions just the x,y,z,values of the array?

Comment: tried pairwise_distances = cdist(zero_indices, one_indices) got and error XA must be a 2-dimensional array